# Error fetching dependencies from Git repo

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, dependencies, git

I have cloned this repo:https://github.com/ClemensElflein/open_mower_ros

however when fetching the dependencies with:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --default-yes
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved  to system dependencies: 
mower_utils: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xbot_msgs] 
mower_msgs: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xesc_msgs] 
mower_simulation: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xbot_positioning]
mower_comms: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xesc_msgs] 
mower_map: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xbot_msgs] 
open_mower: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ftc_local_planner] 
mower_logic: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [xbot_positioning]
```

I have tried many things, but nothing works. I am working on ros-noetic. Any tip?

Comment: There is no guarantee that rosdep can find all the packages you need, or that the package is available for your specific CPU & OS. You may need to build them from source as well. Please edit your post to 1) share the top results of a web search for "xbot_msgs" and 2) explain why it does not solve your first dependency error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't get the [openmower submodules](https://github.com/ClemensElflein/open_mower_ros/blob/main/.gitmodules) (the [readme](https://github.com/ClemensElflein/open_mower_ros/blob/main/README.md) should be changed to mention those prominently)

```
cd open_mower_ros
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

There may be some other packages to git clone manually that aren't in the submodules and can't be installed through rosdep (like the above comment suggests).

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't notice that the repo had git submodules.

Comment: I dont know how to express this, but thank you so much! I was stuck for weeks and couldnt find anything working. You are a savoir!!